# comments extraction from youtube using gwt-youtube-api-1.0.3 in java

Tags: java, youtube, web-scraping, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Trying to retrieve user comments from youtube. The code is given below

```
String videoId = "3u1fu6f8Hto";
    String str = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId + "/comments";
    YouTubeQuery youtubeQuery = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(str));

    youtubeQuery.setMaxResults(50);
    youtubeQuery.setStartIndex(1);

    String videoEntryUrl = youtubeQuery.getUrl().toString();

    VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl), VideoEntry.class);

    String myUrl = youtubeQuery.getUrl().toString();  // only another name

    CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(myUrl), CommentFeed.class); // Feed response
```

The code is showing incompatible types: URL can not be converted to string

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve comments from youtube try doing the following:

```
String commentUrl = videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink().getHref(); 

CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentUrl), CommentFeed.class);
   for(CommentEntry comment : commentFeed.getEntries()) {
         System.out.println(comment.getPlainTextContent());
   }
```

This is a handy link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Comments

Comment: what is videoEntry